# Add meta information (comments), add separate Latex file which only prints meta information

Tags: comments

I want to write some Latex code like this, in file `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

...

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap 1}

...

\section{Sec 1}

\begin{comment-summary}
Some summary text.
\end{comment-summary}

\begin{comment}
Some comment.
\end{comment}

Real text.

\subsection{Sub 1}

...
```

(It doesn't necessarily need to be via `\begin`/`\end`, it could also be a single command. Not sure what would be easier and more clean. I thought that begin/end is maybe cleaner.)

When I compile it normally, I want that I see just "Real text." but not the parts in the comments (`comment` and `comment-summary`).

I can have another Latex file `summary.tex` which would import this `main.tex` file. When I compile this Latex file, I want that I see just the text from `comment-summary`, i.e. "Some summary text." but not the other parts, esp not the "Real text.". However, I do want to see the section structure and the full table of contents.

Is this possible?

I guess related is the question about how to have comments at all, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex).
I guess the [`comment` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) is very useful for this.
But this just answers how I can ignore the content at all (right?).

I guess when I define `comment` and `comment-summary`, I could do it like `\ifnotdefined{comment-summary} \define{comment-summary} <ignore it> ...` (or however that would work exactly in Latex...).
And in `summary.tex`, I could pre-define `comment-summary` to not ignore it, but to actually just print it. So that is reasonable straight-forward.

However, that would still leave the "Real text." unchanged. I have no idea how to remove that. Or is that even possible? I thought about going through `main.tex` but just collect the comment-summary, and write it to a temp file or some variable, and after it went through, just output that. I assume that this is possible, but I have no idea how to do sth like that in Latex.

Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367795/change-section-to-comment) about commenting out whole sections is related to that. Although it uses strange custom sections, and also I don't want to hide specific sections, but basically everything, and just strip out comment-summary.

Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118814/compile-only-a-certain-specified-part-of-the-whole-document) about doing the inverse of `comment` is also very related. But the solution given there is via additional preprocessing and looks specific to tikz.

Note that I have used `comment` and `comment-summary` here as an example, where `comment` would most likely always be removed (unless maybe I want to print just those at some point, who knows...), and `comment-summary` (and only that) would be for such a `summary.tex`. But the whole approach should be generic. There can be many variations, like a Latex file where you print everything (verbose mode or so), etc. And you could also add further tags, like `comment-todos`, etc.

Note that I don't care too much about spacing problems which could arise when I use the comment within part of another paragraph, or in other strange places, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94666/macro-that-defines-a-comment). In my case, a comment, and a comment-summary, etc, would always be a separate paragraph. I assume in that case, there would not be any problems (right?).